# How do I stop label duplication with lightning:inputAddress

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps

My address component on my form has a field label both on top of the field (like normal) and inside the field. How do I get rid of the one inside? When I remove the labels it removes BOTH on top label and inside label.

```
        <lightning:inputAddress aura:id="newForm" 
                                addressLabel="Address"
                                streetLabel="Street"
                                cityLabel="City"
                                countryLabel="Country"
                                provinceLabel="State / Province"
                                postalCodeLabel="PostalCode"
                                street="{!v.newForm.Home_Street_Address__c}"
                                city="{!v.newForm.Home_City__c}"
                                country="{!v.newForm.Home_Country__c}"
                                province="{!v.newForm.Home_State__c}"
                                postalCode="{!v.newForm.Home_Zip__c}"/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text inside the input field is called [Placeholder](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp). Using the [attributes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_inputAddress.htm) of `'lightning:inputAddress'` its not possible to hide it. you can do it by adding [CSS](https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/hide-text-placeholder/) to your lightning component.

```
.THIS ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color:transparent;
}

.THIS :-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   color:transparent; 
}

.THIS ::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   color:transparent; 
}

.THIS :-ms-input-placeholder {  
   color:transparent;
}
```

Comment: This is working for aura component as well, but the only drawback in using this is that it will remove all the other placeholder values which are not of 'lightning:inputaddress' type.

Answer (score 0):

I just set the placeholder values as "":

```
<lightning-input-address  
    street-placeholder="" 
    city-placeholder="" 
    province-placeholder="" 
    postal-code-placeholder="" 
    country-placeholder="">
```

[image: blank placeholders]